# Access nested variables in netcdf variable in R

Tags: r, netcdf

I am confused on how to access nested variables in a netcdf variable 
, sample file ftp://rfdata:forceDATA@ftp.iiasa.ac.at/WFDEI/Tair_WFDEI/Tair_WFDEI_197901.nc.gz)

```
require(ncdf4)
nc=nc_open("Tair_WFDEI_197901.nc")
Tair <- ncvar_get(nc,"Tair")

names(nc$var)
[1] "timestp" "time"    "Tair"  

> nc$var$time
$id
$id
[1] 3

$group_index
[1] -1

$group_id
[1] 65536

$list_index
[1] 2

$isdimvar
[1] FALSE

attr(,"class")
[1] "ncid4"

$name
[1] "time"

$ndims
[1] 1

$natts
[1] 3

$size
[1] 248

$dimids
[1] 2

$prec
[1] "int"

$units
[1] "seconds since 1979-01-01 00:00:00"

$longname
[1] "time since start of month"

$group_index
[1] 1

$chunksizes
[1] NA

$storage
[1] 2

$shuffle
[1] FALSE

$compression
[1] NA

$dims
list()

$dim
$dim[[1]]
$name
[1] "tstep"

$len
[1] 248

$unlim
[1] TRUE

$group_index
[1] 1

$group_id
[1] 65536

$id
[1] 2

$dimvarid
$id
[1] -1

$group_index
[1] 1

$group_id
[1] 65536

$list_index
[1] -1

$isdimvar
[1] TRUE

attr(,"class")
[1] "ncid4"

$vals
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
 [31]  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
 [61]  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
 [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
[121] 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150
[151] 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180
[181] 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210
[211] 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240
[241] 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248

$units
[1] ""

$create_dimvar
[1] FALSE

attr(,"class")
[1] "ncdim4"


$varsize
[1] 248

$unlim
[1] TRUE

$make_missing_value
[1] FALSE

$missval
[1] NA

$hasAddOffset
[1] FALSE

$hasScaleFact
[1] FALSE

attr(,"class")
[1] "ncvar4"
```

I would like to access $vals, but when I try

```
> nc$var$time$vals
NULL
```

also when I try autocomplete in the R console I don't get all the values. I am confused.

```
> nc$var$time$

nc$var$time$id                 nc$var$time$name               nc$var$time$ndims              nc$var$time$natts              
nc$var$time$size               nc$var$time$dimids             nc$var$time$prec               nc$var$time$units              
nc$var$time$longname           nc$var$time$group_index        nc$var$time$chunksizes         nc$var$time$storage            
nc$var$time$shuffle            nc$var$time$compression        nc$var$time$dims               nc$var$time$dim                
nc$var$time$varsize            nc$var$time$unlim              nc$var$time$make_missing_value nc$var$time$missval            
nc$var$time$hasAddOffset       nc$var$time$hasScaleFact
```

Comment: Use `ncvar_get(nc, "time")` instead. And you really should read the help pages of `ncdf4`.

Comment: but my question is about inconsistency

Comment: Then find a better approach alone

Comment: `nc$var$time$id$vars` maybe? Try `str(nc)`, it offers a different view of the data. In my opinion, better than digging through it manually.